# How to make a sample in ppm? (not a specific compound, only the sample)

Tags: experimental-chemistry

Is soaking 1000 mg tea powder in 0.1 L water for about 12 - 24 hours, can be considered as 10000 ppm tea sample?

Could anyone give me reference from a journal or something similar, about my question topic?

Really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: Why do you want this? What for? Who told you "10 000 ppm of tea" is what you need. Is this a school project?  *ppm* sounds scientific, but you need to use it properly!

Comment: Note that ppX units are discouraged from being used because of their vaqueness in many use cases. Also, 100 mL does NOT contain 1000 mg of tea extract, so it cannot be said it is 10000 ppm (w/V) tea extract.

Comment: @Poutnik ppm´s are only vague if used sloppily, but you don´t save sloppy scientific writing and bad reviews that easily. And the BIPM discourages ppb, ppt, because they are seemingly lost in translation, the old fodderheads. One might as well advocate writing up scientific works in "Simple English". ;-)

Comment: @Karl, of course they may be used precisely, but prevention is better than correction. I notice many sloppy ppx unit usage. Also, for non EN speaking countries, ppX units are less used. For ppb, ppt, there also come in the game the language habits, as not everywhere 1 billion is 1000 millions. There are historically the short French scaling system ( which US adopted ) and long English scaling system. US and UK did not agree here until 1974 when UK  accepted US(=French) meaning.  It would not confuse scientists, but it may confuse readers of popular science articles, or of old articles.

Comment: @Poutnik *Writers* of popular science articles are already too often so confused to begin with that it would make very little difference.

Comment: Anyway, if it is frequently seen to use ppx units in vaque or wrong way, it is better to discourage their usage. sometime there are used explicit variants as ppmw, ppmv, ppmn or ppm(V/V),ppm(w/w),ppm(w/V),ppm(n/n).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109675/discussion-between-poutnik-and-karl).

Comment: The main point is that your are not dealing with concentration. You are dealing with a recipe / procedure. And even not dissolving but perhaps extracting (tea powder could be a soluble form or the tea as it is). If something calls for that 10000 ppm, that it simply means what you wrote. If it is you making the protocol, better writing down "the tea was prepared using 1000 mg of xxx in 100 ml hot water" or so. Consider that a good portion of the water can leave during infusion. This is what you need / can do. It relates to the concentration of whatever component of the tea but

Comment: ...it is not a concentration. Still it provides a clear protocol.

Answer (score 2):

In layman's terms, ppm is similar to percentage, i.e., how many parts of X are there in a million. By that standard, 1000 mg tea / 0.1 L is indeed 10000 ppm tea "powder" in water. We are assuming that everything dissolves completely.

Scientifically, or in analytical chemistry, you question is meaningless. Tea powder is mixture so one cannot talk about the ppm of tea powder. This is why you will not find this in journals or books. Concentration is specified for a single component.

Tea powder is a very complex mixture. If we have a mixture of say K2SO4 and NaCl, it is not appropriate to mention the concentration of "salts" in water. It will be an ambiguous statement. A better way would be expressing the concentration of K2SO4 as x% and that of NaCl as y %. It is okay in analytical chemistry to mention "total carbonates" or "total acidity"; here the species being analytes are closely related.

Comment: Hm, I am not sure if concentration must be limited to single component, it makes sense even for soluble mixture. But the problem is, the amount of tea extract is undefined, so I agree it does not have sense in case of tea infusion. It would theoretically still make sense for the original powder, but I do not see much sense in using 10000 ppm instead of 10 g / L, especially as units as ppm, ppb are discouraged to be used for their vagueness.

Comment: It still makes sense to consider mass concentation of dissolved salts or more generally any matter.

Comment: E.g. in water treatment analysis there is determined residual mass after evaporation of the given water volume, expressed as mass concentration of dissolved salts. It is obvious it does not agree with true dissolved salt content because of bicarbonates.

Comment: ppm must be unitless. It can be µg/g, µL/L, apple/megaapple, but NEVER mg/L. That wouldn´t be "vague", but plain *wrong*.

Comment: It can be both vague and wrong. And it is frequently implicitly used for mg/L.

Comment: @Karl ppm is frequently *approximated* in the field of analytical chemistry as mg/L for aqueous solutions, because it is understood that 1 L waters weighs 1 kg. Yes, for physical chemistry work this is not acceptable.